# $\lim _{x\to \infty }x^2\left(1-\sqrt[3]{\frac{\left(x^2-1\right)}{\left(x^2+1\right)}}\right)$

Tags: limits, functions, indeterminate-forms

I really don't know what to try to solve this limit.

$\lim _{x\to \infty }x^2\left(1-\sqrt[3]{\frac{\left(x^2-1\right)}{\left(x^2+1\right)}}\right)$

If I multiply by x^2, it becomes an indeterminate form: + ∞ - ∞

If instead I simplify $1-\sqrt[3]{\frac{\left(x^2-1\right)}{\left(x^2+1\right)}}$ I get to ∞ * 0.

So what could I try?
I don't see a way to rewrite $x^2+1$

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{\frac{\left(x^2-1\right)}{\left(x^2+1\right)}}=\left(1-\frac{2}{x^2+1}\right)^{1/3}$ and use binomial series.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$t=\sqrt[3]{\frac{\left(x^2-1\right)}{\left(x^2+1\right)}}\implies x^2=-{t^3+1\over t^3-1}$$ then

$$\lim _{t\to 1}-{t^3+1\over t^3-1}(1-t )=\lim _{t\to1 }{t^3+1\over t^2+t+1}={2\over 3}$$

Answer (score 1):

series method...
As $x \to \infty$:
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2 - 1}{x^2+1} &= 1 - \frac{2}{x^2} + O(x^{-4})\qquad\text{(long division)}
\\
\left(\frac{x^2 - 1}{x^2+1}\right)^{1/3} &= 1 - \frac{2}{3x^2} + O(x^{-4})
\\
1 - \left(\frac{x^2 - 1}{x^2+1}\right)^{1/3} &= \frac{2}{3x^2} + O(x^{-4})
\\
x^2\left(1 - \left(\frac{x^2 - 1}{x^2+1}\right)^{1/3}\right) &=  \frac{2}{3} + O(x^{-2})
\end{align}
and thus
$$
\lim _{x\to \infty }x^2\left(1-\sqrt[3]{\frac{\left(x^2-1\right)}{\left(x^2+1\right)}}\;\right) = \frac{2}{3}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $$\frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2+1}-\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}}{\sqrt[3]{x^2+1}}$$
and multiply numerator and denominator by
$$\sqrt[3]{x^2+1}^2+\sqrt{x^2+1}\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}+\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}^2$$

Answer (score 0):

As usual,

$$1-\sqrt[3]z=\frac{1-z}{1+\sqrt[3]z+\sqrt[3]z^2}$$ and with

$$z:=\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}$$

the denominator tends to $3$ so that the limit reduces to that of

$$\frac13x^2\left(1-\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right).$$

> $$\frac23.$$

Answer (score 0):

You may set $x^2=\frac 1t$ and consider $t\to 0^+$.

Then, you only need the derivatives

- $(\star)$: $(\sqrt[3]{1-t})' =-\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{(1-t)^2}}$ and $(\sqrt[3]{1+t})'=\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{(1+t)^2}}$:

\begin{eqnarray*}x^2\left(1-\sqrt[3]{\frac{\left(x^2-1\right)}{\left(x^2+1\right)}}\right)
& \stackrel{x^2=\frac 1t}{=} & \frac{1-\sqrt[3]{\frac{1-t}{1+t}}}{t}\\
& = & \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1+t}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt[3]{1+t} - \sqrt[3]{1-t}}{t} \\
& = & \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1+t}}\cdot \left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+t} -1 }{t} - \frac{\sqrt[3]{1-t} -1}{t}\right) \\
& \stackrel{t \to 0^+}{\longrightarrow} & \left. (\sqrt[3]{1+t})'\right|_{t=0} - \left. (\sqrt[3]{1-t})'\right|_{t=0}\\
& \stackrel{(\star)}{=} & \frac 13 + \frac 13 = \frac{2}{3}
\end{eqnarray*}